# How do I use the --with-cpu and --with-arch when cross compiling stuff like gcc binutils and glibc

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, glibc, autotools, binutils

I need to target armv7-a I dont know how to make it compile for armv7. It is instead using armv5te when the binaries are installed using make install
I want to do

```
./configure --host=arm-eabi --target=arm-eabi --with-arch --with-cpu
```

Comment: The `--with-arch` and `--with-cpu` options are specific to the project you are trying to build.  You might glean some information from running `./configure --help`, and if that's not enough then you might consider reading the project's documentation for builders.

Comment: However, Autotools `--with-foo` options can take an argument, and `-with-arch` and `--with-cpu` don't seem like they would make sense without one.  *At a guess*, then, these options expect you to name a particular architecture or CPU, something along the lines of `--with-cpu=arm7`.  If so, then you'll absolutely need to consult the docs to determine the actual argument required.

Comment: I had been trying all variants of --with-cpu=arm7 and the like with no luck. ./configure wasn't setting necessary CFLAGS using --with-cpu and --with-arch and it didint complai that they were useless/ not being used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I instead used the `./configure CFLAGS='-mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4'` and the binaries are no longer compiled for armv5te. Thanks Everyone